# convert time format in db to jquery countdown format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have field in db contain date in the format '2012-09-21 09:25:00'  I am doing a jquery

countdown function but there I need the date format in 'Fri Sep 21 2012 09:25:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'

so how to covert '2012-09-21 09:25:00' to 'Fri Sep 21 2012 09:25:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'

using jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a time format that I got from PHP to a format that jQuery countdown accepts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457941/how-to-convert-a-time-format-that-i-got-from-php-to-a-format-that-jquery-countdo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the link below for the solution of your problem. Hope this helps :)

[How to convert a time format that I got from PHP to a format that jQuery countdown accepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457941/how-to-convert-a-time-format-that-i-got-from-php-to-a-format-that-jquery-countdo)

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the date in ISO format.

This piece of code can help you

```
$iso_date = date('c', strtotime('2012-09-21 09:25:00'));
```

Hope that helps you.