# Convert PHP time to Javascript time in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, time

How to convert PHP time to Javascript time in PHP? My PHP code:

```
<?php
$times = array(/* A list of time with "Y-m-d h:i:s" format goes here */);
$return = '[';
$i = 1;
foreach($times as $time) {
  $return .= '['.strtotime($time).','.$i.'],';
  //In my opinion, converting time to
  //js time at here is good choice
  if($i==100) {
    break;
  }
  $i++;
}
$return = substr($return, 0, -1).']';
?>
```

My script:

```
<script>
var results = [{
  label: "Buy in",
  data: <?=$return?>
}];
</script>
```

Comment: If I think correctly. Maybe js time = php time*1000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the output of PHP's `date()` and  Javascript time is in the same format, but multiplied by 1000 because it has millisecond resolution.

Comment: Well done NullPoint, quanganh_developer please try to use google before asking :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403410/question-about-time-functions-in-php-and-javascript-particularly-the-gettime-fun

Comment: Thank you @NullPoint! Just my mistake:D! Thank @Jared Drake too!

Answer (score 0):

Final code:

```
 <?php
      $times = array(/* A list of time with "Y-m-d h:i:s" format goes here */);
      $return = '[';
      $i = 1;
      foreach($times as $time)
      {
          $return .= ('['.strtotime($time)*1000).','.$i.'],';
          if($i==100)
          {
              break;
          }
          $i++;
      }
      $return = substr($return, 0, -1).']';
 ?>
```

Thank you very much:D! Some time I have stupid thinking like :"How to call js function from php code" for this case. I have to learn more and more...